# Use objects in Enum (Specifically Place in GWT)

Tags: java, gwt, enums

I got an application in GWT that will consist of a listbox with more than 50 items. When selecting one I'll go to the corresponding place.

To avoid hard coded values and to share with the server part, I created an Enum lets call it TableEnum
So Table Enum is composed of a key and a displayName.
Which I then use to fill my combo. Once the selection is done, I got the value and so need to get the Place to go to.
That's why I created a factory that take the value of the selection and return a Place object.

First solution I was about to do is transform my value in TableEnum object et do a switch/case creating the correct associated Place.

But I was also thinking about adding the Place directly as a field of my Enum. This would avoid the switch/case and I would only need to do tableEnum.getPlace().

But I'm not really confident that this can be called a good practice. In my head Enum were simple objects not really knowing what was around them.

Thanks for information

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Enums in Java are not just a placeholder for integers, or just some constants (such as some languages). Enums are classes with fixed number of objects, so **it is a good practice to give your enums more brain**, and always forget about lots of **if/else** or **switch/case**es.

Comment: I'll go with your words as it fits what I was thinking. If someone has a good article on the subject thanks to post it ;)

Answer (score 2):

If each item in the enum is associated to only one place, you can create an abstract method on your enum to get the place.

```
public enum TableEnum {
    FIRST(){
       public Place getPlace(){ return new FirstPlace(); }
    },
    SECOND(){
       public Place getPlace(){ return new SecondPlace(); }
    };

    public abstract Place getPlace();
}
```

Later, you can access the place like so:

```
TableEnum t = ...
t.getPlace()
```

Comment: Thanks I know that, the question was if it was a good idea or not.

Answer (score 2):

like Danny Kirchmeier's, but maybe less code:

```
enum Table {
    first(Place.place1), second(Place.place2);
    Table(Place place) {
        this.place = place;
    }
    final Place place;
}
```

maybe your place should be an enum?

Comment: Certainly a valid solution, but only if the Places can be statically created. These places will be created only once and will be held in memory at all times. Conversely, Places are created on demand in my version.